# get value of select element when submitting form

Tags: html

I have this HTML form:

```
<form id="form1">
    <select name="date" class="form-control">

    </select> <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save" onclick="SubmitForm('#form1', 'editcustomer_callusage.php?date=', '.EditCustomer');" class="btn btn-default" />
    </form>
```

how can i put the selected value in the `date` select element into the `onclick` function on the button?

Comment: Why are you using a stack of JavaScript instead of just a regular form submission?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for...

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
    var d = $('[name=date]').val()
});
```

Not *completely* sure the whole '[name=date]' thing will work, if it doesn't just give the date an ID and find it the same way you found submit.

Lemme know if this works for ya!